RowEncoder.apply(schema).resolveAndBind() and Row/InternalRow serializer/deserializer equivalent in Spark 3.5
We use RowEncoder.apply(schema).resolveAndBind() in Spark 3.1 to create ExpressionEncoder[row] and create a serializer and deserializer from it.
val encoder = Encoders.row(schema).resolveAndBind()
val serializer = encoder.createSerializer()
val deserializer = encoder.createDeserializer()

We have to upgrade to Spark 3.5 and RowEncoder.apply() is unavailable in Spark 3.5. I know we can use Encoders.row(schema) to replace RowEncoder.apply(schema), but how do I create the serializer and deserializer for the Row to internalRow and vice versa conversion?
I've tried to look through how to use Encoder[Row] but still don't understand how to create the serializer/deserializer

// currently in 3.5/4 prev it's an ExpressionEncoder
val renc = Encoders.row(structType).asInstanceOf[ExpressionEncoder]
val encoder = renc.resolveAndBind()
val serializer = encoder.createSerializer()
val deserializer = encoder.createDeserializer()

should be fine (see here for .row being ExpressionEncoder).  It'd be interesting to see what use-case you have for this, it's quite internal and directly calling resolveAndBind can lead to issues (with Expressions you are better having the encoder as a parameter to be resolved), there may be a better way.
